# MPLAB Harmony Timer triggers once and stops the chip

Tags: timer, mplab

I have MPLAB X v 6.05 and am using harmony 3 on a pic32mx795 device. I made a simple program to toggle the output of a pin connected to an led. It works, but only once. After Tmr1 triggers (2.5sec), it doesn't seem to exit the interrupt routine and doesn't get back to the main loop. -After it triggers, the LED_Toggle in the main loop stops. How can I fix this?

Main:

```
#include <stddef.h>                     // Defines NULL
#include <stdbool.h>                    // Defines true
#include <stdlib.h>                     // Defines EXIT_FAILURE
#include "definitions.h"                // SYS function prototypes

// *****************************************************************************
// *****************************************************************************
// Section: Main Entry Point
// *****************************************************************************
// *****************************************************************************
void myTmr1_ISR(uint32_t status, uintptr_t context);


int main ( void )
{
    /* Initialize all modules */
    SYS_Initialize ( NULL );
    LED_1_Clear();
    LED_1_Toggle();
    
    TMR1_CallbackRegister(myTmr1_ISR, 0);
    TMR1_Start ();    
    
    int num = 0;
    while ( true )
    {
        
        /* Maintain state machines of all polled MPLAB Harmony modules. */
        SYS_Tasks ( );
        num++;
        if(num >= 5000)
        {            
            LED_1_Toggle();
            num = 0;
        }
    }

    /* Execution should not come here during normal operation */

    return ( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

void myTmr1_ISR(uint32_t status, uintptr_t context)
{
    LED_1_Toggle();
}
```

plib_tmr1.c

```
#include "device.h"
#include "plib_tmr1.h"

static TMR1_TIMER_OBJECT tmr1Obj;

void TMR1_Initialize(void)
{
    /* Disable Timer */
    T1CONCLR = _T1CON_ON_MASK;

    /*
    SIDL = 0
    TWDIS = 1
    TGATE = 0
    TCKPS = 3
    TSYNC = 0
    TCS = 0
    */
    T1CONSET = 0x1030;

    /* Clear counter */
    TMR1 = 0x0;

    /*Set period */
    PR1 = 30516;

    /* Setup TMR1 Interrupt */
    TMR1_InterruptEnable();  /* Enable interrupt on the way out */
}


void TMR1_Start (void)
{
    T1CONSET = _T1CON_ON_MASK;
}


void TMR1_Stop (void)
{
    T1CONCLR = _T1CON_ON_MASK;
}


void TMR1_PeriodSet(uint16_t period)
{
    PR1 = period;
}


uint16_t TMR1_PeriodGet(void)
{
    return (uint16_t)PR1;
}


uint16_t TMR1_CounterGet(void)
{
    return(TMR1);
}

uint32_t TMR1_FrequencyGet(void)
{
    return (12207);
}

void TIMER_1_InterruptHandler (void)
{
    uint32_t status = IFS0bits.T1IF;
    IFS0CLR = _IFS0_T1IF_MASK;

    if((tmr1Obj.callback_fn != NULL))
    {
        tmr1Obj.callback_fn(status, tmr1Obj.context);
    }
}


void TMR1_InterruptEnable(void)
{
    IEC0SET = _IEC0_T1IE_MASK;
}


void TMR1_InterruptDisable(void)
{
    IEC0CLR = _IEC0_T1IE_MASK;
}


void TMR1_CallbackRegister( TMR1_CALLBACK callback_fn, uintptr_t context )
{
    /* - Save callback_fn and context in local memory */
    tmr1Obj.callback_fn = callback_fn;
    tmr1Obj.context = context;
}
```

interrupt.c

```
#include "interrupts.h"
#include "definitions.h"

// *****************************************************************************
// *****************************************************************************
// Section: System Interrupt Vector Functions
// *****************************************************************************
// *****************************************************************************


/* All the handlers are defined here.  Each will call its PLIB-specific function. */
void __ISR(_TIMER_1_VECTOR, ipl1SOFT) TIMER_1_Handler (void)
{
    
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, with tmr1, harmony didn't put the InterruptHandler() line in interrupts.c. I switched to TMR2, and it added the line automatically. I guess it would have worked if I added the tmr1 handler myself but then any time changes to the MCC get regenerated, it will replace the code.

```
/* All the handlers are defined here.  Each will call its PLIB-specific function. */
void __ISR(_TIMER_2_VECTOR, ipl1SOFT) TIMER_2_Handler (void)
{
    TIMER_2_InterruptHandler();
}
```